# Python scrap useful information from webpage with login

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

By referring https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-scrape-data-from-a-website-using-python-for-beginner-5c770a1fbe2d I have started scraping data from a website with login information.
My website is a bit different and I got result. But it is in a different format.
code:

```
from pprint import pprint
import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cookies = {
    'CFID': '180615757',
    'CFTOKEN': '64089929988eb934-58E2ACC9-AD21-785B-2AFBCE86106B41FE',
    'visid_incap_2388351': '0Vmr7QpDRvmVw8fbXUJFkB5XEWMAAAAAQUIPAAAAAADtlXunU/D8GLU5VofHHier',
    '_ga_6ZQNJ4ELG2': 'GS1.1.1662315508.15.1.1662315668.0.0.0',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.147261521.1662080801',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.1149490171.1662080801',
    'reese84': '3:yMGXsdMquwoCj3IoSFRCMg==:Vf20HwL77P8oWYTTKbE0XigwyQE3d2lLQpPVoZYcoL8SJTmLeqAani+7GspfC2BiJYOOytBlkIp9MewLgs/XbkaiLrSvLnMdZ0aT8/M9FvBohByybnJXNl25ya/yfpGhL9oT1HKMZYnKqSR0Sg8+nHTUEO0/YErJgQmfoeYIT4kmE01S8cndGIemtuGjvq1hzB/D9VAQL7S3idutOumBNu84j5FyCdOBClCJTriE+X9j40lj1swIxFlryTmBAtLHnEvN9M57N4LMb13yuSBaCawrv4fnron0JnUvfKpLU0CXTnpcM9hJNGv9Ekb4Ap43CZDPdeLVzEmj+39wCVtXPtMqBNCU6mPVBSeJCRHyRuQjY+y0Sv5w7ME2LXhT8bEGHyE8yeuxddxvoG51STebu+pb0mSp5n+iKotUEn9h+sA=:WH64twwKGqtE4pUorYOeGylONeXRsfG+3Qe3zAfpdrs=',
    '__atuvc': '65%7C35%2C2%7C36',
    'COOKIESTATUS': 'ON',
    'HIDECOOKIEBANNER': 'TRUE',
    'nlbi_2388351': 'jGGxMFazFBqnU+x+okRrFAAAAAC/AJ/k+R2U+vs5Q4LIRTS7',
    'nlbi_2388351_2147483392': 'PUildkEvtiZ9uje3okRrFAAAAABv1NR/7gPLX7Lc/iS5ei8N',
    'incap_ses_989_2388351': 'mWy+Uq7aLX000xomDaO5DfTrFGMAAAAA6XmB42vG5CO6i609/RhyKg==',
    'incap_ses_468_2388351': 'sDNcR2labTHyNXYlUqx+BipAFGMAAAAAImV2A07lGANZGfpvhvPlLg==',
    '__atuvs': '6314ec0cdbe92a78001',
    '_gat_gtag_UA_12825325_1': '1',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    # 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.higheredjobs.com/admin/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'Cookie': 'CFID=180615757; CFTOKEN=64089929988eb934-58E2ACC9-AD21-785B-2AFBCE86106B41FE; visid_incap_2388351=0Vmr7QpDRvmVw8fbXUJFkB5XEWMAAAAAQUIPAAAAAADtlXunU/D8GLU5VofHHier; _ga_6ZQNJ4ELG2=GS1.1.1662315508.15.1.1662315668.0.0.0; _ga=GA1.2.147261521.1662080801; _gid=GA1.2.1149490171.1662080801; reese84=3:yMGXsdMquwoCj3IoSFRCMg==:Vf20HwL77P8oWYTTKbE0XigwyQE3d2lLQpPVoZYcoL8SJTmLeqAani+7GspfC2BiJYOOytBlkIp9MewLgs/XbkaiLrSvLnMdZ0aT8/M9FvBohByybnJXNl25ya/yfpGhL9oT1HKMZYnKqSR0Sg8+nHTUEO0/YErJgQmfoeYIT4kmE01S8cndGIemtuGjvq1hzB/D9VAQL7S3idutOumBNu84j5FyCdOBClCJTriE+X9j40lj1swIxFlryTmBAtLHnEvN9M57N4LMb13yuSBaCawrv4fnron0JnUvfKpLU0CXTnpcM9hJNGv9Ekb4Ap43CZDPdeLVzEmj+39wCVtXPtMqBNCU6mPVBSeJCRHyRuQjY+y0Sv5w7ME2LXhT8bEGHyE8yeuxddxvoG51STebu+pb0mSp5n+iKotUEn9h+sA=:WH64twwKGqtE4pUorYOeGylONeXRsfG+3Qe3zAfpdrs=; __atuvc=65%7C35%2C2%7C36; COOKIESTATUS=ON; HIDECOOKIEBANNER=TRUE; nlbi_2388351=jGGxMFazFBqnU+x+okRrFAAAAAC/AJ/k+R2U+vs5Q4LIRTS7; nlbi_2388351_2147483392=PUildkEvtiZ9uje3okRrFAAAAABv1NR/7gPLX7Lc/iS5ei8N; incap_ses_989_2388351=mWy+Uq7aLX000xomDaO5DfTrFGMAAAAA6XmB42vG5CO6i609/RhyKg==; incap_ses_468_2388351=sDNcR2labTHyNXYlUqx+BipAFGMAAAAAImV2A07lGANZGfpvhvPlLg==; __atuvs=6314ec0cdbe92a78001; _gat_gtag_UA_12825325_1=1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    # Requests doesn't support trailers
    # 'TE': 'trailers',
}

params = {
    'JobCat': '141',
    'CatName': 'Academic Advising',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.higheredjobs.com/admin/search.cfm', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')#'lxml')#
job_title = soup.find_all('div',class_=["row record","col-sm-5 text-sm-right"])
jobs_list = []
for i in job_title:
 name = i.text
 jobs_list.append(name)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Jobs title':jobs_list})
```

Present output:

```
df = 
Jobs title
0   \n\nRe-Sort\n\n\r\n\t\t\tResults 1 - 70 of 70\...
1   \n\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAssistant Profes...
2   \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t...
```

Expected output:

```
df = 
     Jobs title                     Company name                   location         Posted
0   Assistant Professor/Associate  University of Southern Indiana  Evansville, IN   09/02/22
    Professor of Engineering, 
    Pott College of Science, 
    Engineering, and Education - F22057F1
```

Comment: Can you confirm the url you are trying to scrape data from?

Comment: You mean, should I post the url?

Comment: Please format your code properly so that it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue is that you try to create your `DataFrame` from unstructured data, that is collected in your `list`.

So try to structure it first e.g. as `dict`, append it to your `list` and then create your `DataFrame`:

```
jobs_list = []
for i in soup.select('.row.record'):
    
    jobs_list.append(dict(zip(['title','university','location','study','date'],i.stripped_strings)))

pd.DataFrame(jobs_list)
```

**Note:** *If you like to change the headers, change this `list` -> ['title','university','location','study','date']*

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html ='''
<div class="row record">
<div class="col-sm-7"><a href="details.cfm?JobCode=178085874&amp;Title=Assistant%20Professor%2FAssociate%20Professor%20of%20Engineering%2C%20Pott%20College%20of%20Science%2C%20Engineering%2C%20and%20Education%20%2D%20F22057F1">
                                            Assistant Professor/Associate Professor of Engineering, Pott College of Science, Engineering, and Education - F22057F1</a>
<br/>
                                        University of Southern Indiana <br/>
                                            Evansville, IN 
                                    </div>
<div class="col-sm-5 text-sm-right">
                                        
                                        Electrical Engineering 
                                            <br/> Posted 09/02/22<br/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row record">
<div class="col-sm-7">
<a href="details.cfm?JobCode=178085843&amp;Title=Assistant%20Professor%20of%20Engineering%20F99507">
                                            Assistant Professor of Engineering F99507</a>
<br/>
                                        McNeese State University <br/>
                                            Lake Charles, LA 
                                    </div>
<div class="col-sm-5 text-sm-right">
                                        
                                        Electrical Engineering 
                                            <br/> Posted 09/02/22<br/>
</div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

jobs_list = []
for i in soup.select('.row.record'):
    
    jobs_list.append(dict(zip(['title','university','location','study','date'],i.stripped_strings)))

pd.DataFrame(jobs_list)
```

##### Output

|  | title | university | location | study | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Assistant Professor/Associate Professor of Engineering, Pott College of Science, Engineering, and Education - F22057F1 | University of Southern Indiana | Evansville, IN | Electrical Engineering | Posted 09/02/22 |
| 1 | Assistant Professor of Engineering F99507 | McNeese State University | Lake Charles, LA | Electrical Engineering | Posted 09/02/22 |

Comment: One more question: I want to add few more columns to this table. For that I have to click each position and will get the information. Like Salary. How do I add that?

Comment: To keep focus of your original question - This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus - Hint: iterate over each url and store information from each detail page in your list.

Comment: Sure! I will ask another question. In the above question, how do drop "Posted" in the 'date' column? This helps me to perform operations based on the date. `df['date'] = df['date'].str.replace('Posted','')` This is working but Is there a better way?

Comment: A better way would be to collect it in expected structure - Believe  me this will be fixed with your next question scraping the detail page, cause this has an ideal structure to creating the dict more generic. :)

Answer (score 1):

To remove newlines meaning  `\n\t` , you can invoke `get_text()` property instead  of `.text`

```
name = i.get_text(strip=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a complete example of how you can extract the jobs under 'Academic Advising' from that website:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from tqdm import tqdm

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
big_list = []
for x in tqdm(range(1, 1337, 100)):
    url = f'https://www.higheredjobs.com/admin/search.cfm?JobCat=141&StartRow={x}&SortBy=4&NumJobs=100'
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
    jobs = soup.select_one('div#js-results').select('div[class="row record"]')
    for job in jobs:
        job_title = job.select_one('a').get_text(strip=True)
        job_url = job.select_one('a').get('href')
        big_list.append((job_title, job_url))
df = pd.DataFrame(list(set(big_list)), columns = ['Job', 'Url'])
print(df)
```

Result is a dataframe with all those jobs (1337):

```
Job Url
0   Director, Usha Kundu, MD College of Health Adv...   details.cfm?JobCode=178071028&Title=Director%2...
1   Academic Advisor, College of Natural, Behavior...   details.cfm?JobCode=178061977&Title=Academic%2...
2   Part-Time Academic Advisor for EAP & Foreign L...   details.cfm?JobCode=177870235&Title=Part%2DTim...
3   Student Service Assistant ll (Temp) details.cfm?JobCode=178044985&Title=Student%20...
4   On-Call Academic Advisor (Applicant Pool)   details.cfm?JobCode=177522145&Title=On%2DCall%...
... ... ...
1332    Part-Time Academic Support Coach    details.cfm?JobCode=178060131&Title=Part%2DTim...
1333    Academic Advisor    details.cfm?JobCode=178005430&Title=Academic%2...
1334    Retention Coordinator/Academic Advisor  details.cfm?JobCode=178077784&Title=Retention%...
1335    P220178 - Academic Advisor, School of Public H...   details.cfm?JobCode=177930648&Title=P220178%20...
1336    Director of Academic Advising - Georgetown Uni...   details.cfm?JobCode=178021588&Title=Director%2...
```